# Succinct word or phrase to begin quoting approximately what someone said

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I would like a more concise way of phrasing what is bracketed in the examples below:

> Socrates [said something along the lines of] I'm smart because I know that I don't know much.
>
> Tyler [said something like] success breeds a hidden failure.

Comment: Largely covered at [How do you punctuate something you paraphrased?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69951/how-do-you-punctuate-something-you-paraphrased).

Comment: Just to combine the answer with the examples you've provided... 'Socrates said, and I'm paraphrasing here: I'm smart because I know that I don't know much.' Something like that.

Comment: You can just use "claimed" or "suggested" or similar.  Those verbs do not convey "what follows is an exact quotation".

Comment: I'd probably stick with "said something like", actually.  At three words, it's as concise as it needs to be, IMO.

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/38322/68817): Can I change how to accomplish something once someone says “or ['something to that effect'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=said+something+to+the+effect%2Csaid+something+along+the+lines&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csaid%20something%20to%20the%20effect%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csaid%20something%20along%20the%20lines%3B%2Cc0)”?

Comment: With Socrates in English though, you can really only ever quote a translation of a quote which might already be a paraphrase, since we have no original writings and he spoke Ancient Greek.

Comment: Another option, which might be too sophisticated, could be "Socrates nonverbatim said...". Otherwise, I also think that a mere "along the lines of" might be suitable.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you're being informal:

> Socrates was like "I'm smart because I know that I don't know much."

or

> Tyler was all "Success breeds a hidden failure."

In at least my idiolect, "was like" as opposed to "said" is precisely to indicate that the source is being paraphrased.

*Like* — [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/like)

> *adverb* 2. (informal) Used to convey a person's reported attitude or feelings in the form of direct speech (whether or not representing an actual quotation)
>
> *"so she comes into the room and she's like ‘Where is everybody?’"*

Comment: +1 I've added a dictionary reference to support your answer. :)

Comment: This is incrwdibly bad advice. Don't even think of talking like this around educated people, unless you want them to walk away thinking like wow man, guy doesn't even, like, ya know, like, speak english.

Comment: Qualitative likes are actually considered serious English now, according to like, some report I heard on NPR.

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I was thinking (and it's why those phrases are not the abomination some folks assert—they serve a conversational purpose that is different from "he said"). It should be noted that it's best to use these fairly sparingly and, as the answer says, in fairly casual contexts, unless you're very young. For example, I have heard them used by highly educated academics in water cooler-type situations, but not in faculty meetings.

Comment: ´+1, but I would perhaps add a warning that this should only be used in quite informal spoken contexts, and perhaps never in serious writing.

Comment: It could be used for humorous effect in writing, but I think one would need to prepare the reader by adopting a similar tone in the rest of the work.

Comment: Particularly, in case Second language learners may get the wrong impression. It is important to note that is **very casual** language, only used in conversation and not generally with older people. It's becoming more widely accepted but you will sound like a teenager.

Comment: @TomKelly It provides a nice alternative to your answer at the opposite end of the spectrum (both upvoted though I'd be *much* more likely to use your version even on facebook)

Comment: @mobileink: I'm a PhD and I talk like this. I think that qualifies me as "educated people". It's very useful to convey someone's beliefs or manner by "putting words in their mouth" without claiming they actually said those words. Perhaps the quality that makes some people object to useful linguistic innovation isn't being educated, but being pretentious?

Comment: @Kundor: It's a sociological judgment, not a moral one.  Probably at least partly generational.  Using "like" in this way sends a very clear signal that the speaker has very limited verbal skills.

Comment: @ChrisH Sure, both are appropriate in different contexts. I feel like there isn't enough care to warn non-native speakers of the casual nature though, given the proper looking dictionary definition and all.

Comment: @TomKelly I wouldn't worry too much, the OP said "If you're being informal" and the cited definition specifically has "(informal)" beside it. If you look up [what Oxford Dictionaries include with this provisio](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/usage/informal-language), you'd see there's little overlap with professional speech.

Comment: @mobileink educated people may well understand a wide range of registers...  and even use them too! I don't think the fact someone uses "like" implies that they can't use more formal constructions where those would be more appropriate.

Comment: @mobileink I would say that the message is more correctly that the speaker has chosen to apply minimal effort in selecting the wording.  When the (perceived) lack of effort is acceptable, this is a concise and accurate phrasing.  When it is not, it comes across as rude.  Rudeness is often interpreted as ignorance of manners, which in this context is only a small step away to ignorance of alternatives (i.e. reduced vocabulary/verbal skills.)

Comment: @mobileink Further, given people's propensity to respond insultingly when offended, it is understandable that some would accuse the speaker of various shortcomings when they feel disrespected by the lack of effort. Combine this with projection and false consensus biases, and you get many people declaring "uneducated" what is simply a modern, informal turn of phrase that is both useful and appropriate in certain situations.

Comment: Similar but less colloquial, "it's like he/she said...". Examples: "it's like Socrates said..." or "it's like what Socrates used to say...".

Answer (score 74):

To quote approximately is to **[paraphrase](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/paraphrase)**:

> a restatement of a text or passage giving the meaning in another form

<sup>(Dictionary.com)</sup>

In order to use this word, you'd have to restructure your sentences:

> To paraphrase Socrates: I'm smart because I know that I don't know much.
>
> To paraphrase Tyler: success breeds a hidden failure.

Comment: This will change the meaning of the text, because in OP example subject of the sentence is Socrates and in yours the subject is the author of the text.

Comment: @jcubic - It won't change the meaning: "I kicked the ball" has the same meaning as "The ball was kicked by me". It will, however, change the structure. You'll see that I already know this, and admit it: my answer contains the words "In order to use this word, you'd have to restructure your sentences". Often for <single-word-requests> and <phrase-requests> some rewording is needed, as English doesn't have words of every type for every situation; often it's a case of finding the best one and restructuring to use it. [cont...]

Comment: [...cont] If the structure is all-important to the OP, he is welcome to pick one of the other answers. [Kundor's](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/367620/91730) is pretty good, as long as the OP is happy with informality.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of going out of your way to make it look like a quote but then disclaim that it's an exact quote, you can indicate that you are paraphrasing what someone else said by avoiding making it look like a quotation in the first place.

For example, if you are talking about something another person said, use the third person to indicate that you are restating what they said, and not directly quoting them. Instead of:

> Bob said "I am going to the store."

you can say:

> Bob said *he was* going to the store.

Both convey the same meaning, that Bob intended to go to the store, but the first implies a specific wording was used by Bob, and the second does not.

For your examples, you could write something like:

> Socrates *said that he was* smart because *he knew that he didn't* know much.
>
> Tyler *said that* success breeds a hidden failure.

Comment: This works fine as a rewrite of the OP's sentence, but it doesn't provide the succinctness he asked for.

Comment: @AndyT How about: _Socrates said he was smart because he knew that he didn't know much._ The second example is even more straightforward to adjust (as you don't have to remove any first person): _Tyler said that success breeds a hidden failure._

Comment: @R.M. - Well, that removes the whole "something along the lines of" part that the OP is looking for.

Comment: @AndyT - Not really, as the convention is that if you don't have quotation marks it's a paraphrase/rewording - you're capturing the meaning but not the exact words. The "something along the lines of" is implicit. As long as you're "quoting approximately" and not doing something like introducing a new analogy (_"Tyler said winning the Superbowl puts you last for the draft."_) you shouldn't need to explicitly signpost it. -- But you're right that it doesn't *emphasize* that it's a paraphrase; though I'm unclear if the OP needs that, or simply needs to mark that it's not a direct quote.

Comment: @R.M. - You are right, I think I was being a bit slow yesterday. barcebue - I've edited your post to try and make it a bit clearer (it makes it clearer to me anyway). Feel free to revert if you don't like it.

Answer (score 14):

More colloquially, I've heard **more or less**.

> Socrates more or less said I'm smart because I don't know that much.
>
> More or less, Socrates said that I'm smart because I don't know that much.
>
> He said I'm smart because I don't know that much, more or less.

This phrase indicates that you're paraphrasing, or that you're 'reading between the lines', e.g.:

> He said "That dress looks fine on you".
>
> More or less, he said I look fat in this dress!

Comment: I like the use of the term, but disagree with where you put it in the sentence in your first two examples. We don't want to modify *said*, that would imply that Socrates didn't actually *say* it (maybe he mumbled it, or wrote it, or conveyed it through smoke signals). Instead, make sure you're modifying *what* he said: "Socrates said, more or less, I'm smart because I don't know what much". Your third example works.

Answer (score 9):

If you're going for down-to-the-syllable succinctness, try out **roughly**.

> Socrates roughly said: I'm smart because I know that I don't know much.
>
> Tyler roughly said: success breeds a hidden failure.

Comment: You could use "basically" or "essentially" along the same lines.

Comment: @AndyT Ok, done.

Comment: *Roughly*, where you put it in the sentence, could be seen as describing a gravely voice. Try putting it *after* the word *said*: "Socrates said, roughly, I'm smart because I don't know that much.". I like "essentially" very much, it seems slightly more formal and more likely to be used in writing.

Answer (score 7):

While I agree with some of the answers, an alternative approach is to use words that show your understanding on their stance of role in the idea:

> Socrates **acknowledged** that [he was] smart because [he knew] that [he] don't know much.
>
> Tyler was **critical of** success [because it] breeds a hidden failure.

Note here that this is fairly formal (third-person past tense) and would come across as more impartial, objective, or academic in a report or article. You might come across as too educated, condescending or patronising if you were to use this in everyday speech or social media.

Comment: This appeared in the comments, too: please notice that the heavy lifting in the first example is not the word "acknowledged" (which could just as easily be rewritten "said") but rather the rewrite into 3rd person singular, which signals "hey, Socrates wouldn't have said this directly because he'd have been speaking in the 1st person; maybe there are other variances as well."

Comment: I think both are important to consider, word choice is an important part of your repertoire: it is a great way your or their stance on the phrase. Particularly, as "concise" was requested by the OP. Similarly, _claimed_, _postulated_ or _hypothesised_ can show that the idea is uncertain or remains controversial.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a phrase you could try:

You could say your paraphrased sentence and add, ***'or words to that effect.'***

E.g., Socrates said he wasn't smart because he knew he didn't know much, or something to that effect.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to "roughly", you can use "basically" or "essentially"

> Socrates *basically* said I'm smart because I know that I don't know much.
>
> Tyler *essentially* said that success breeds a hidden failure.

These are both fairly concise and appropriate in a range of situations: they're a little bit informal (particularly "basically") but I have seen these used in academic debates and conferences.

Answer (score 1):

Since we only know the quote *approximately*, we know the *meaning* of the quote, and so ***meant*** should work.

> Socrates ***meant***, "I'm smart because I know that I don't know much."
>
> Tyler ***meant*** success breeds a hidden failure.

ODO:

> **[mean](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mean)**
>   *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   **1** Intend to convey or refer to (a particular thing); signify:
>   ‘he was asked to clarify what his remarks ***meant***’
>
> ‘Ziana began to understand what her grandfather had ***meant*** by those
>   words.’

Answer (score 1):

There are already excellent answers here, but to convey the meaning of the OP, may I suggest

**Taught**

> Socrates taught, "I'm smart because I know that I don't know much."
>
> Tyler taught, "Success breeds a hidden failure."

This implies that the words chosen might not be exact, but the meaning is the same.  In essence you are quoting his idea, not his words.  Ideas, by design, are framed in the language and perspective of the person speaking and not that of the original creator.

Comment: do you mean `thought` ?

Comment: The use of this is fairly restricted to teachers and I'm not sure I agree with it. Teachers tend to use the 2nd/3rd person for this so: Socrates taught that "to be smart is to know that you don't know very much". Using first person wouldn't be very appropriate to a student audience where you're clearly "smarter". Similarly, _proposed that_ or _suggested that_ would be serve a similarly purpose to refer to their claims in writing or research rather than teachings.

Comment: I think you are correct.  I will leave this answer for knowledge sake.

Answer (score 1):

Consider "**indicated**", this sense of which is defined by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indicate) as:

> to state or express briefly

As in:

> Tyler **indicated that** success breeds a hidden failure.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is not to use quotes. You could use 'that" if you want to emphasize that it's not a direct quote, but it's not necessary.

Tyler said [that] success breeds a hidden failure. Socrates said [that] he was smart because he knew he didn't know much.

If you know what your speaker meant, but don't know the exact words, this should do. 
If you're not sure of the exact meaning, then you'll have admit that by using some more cumbersome wording. Something along the lines of "something along the lines of."